I can't install MedusaJS after I tried updating my Postgres on Windows
I had Postgres 15 on my Windows machine. I was able to install MedusaJS using their npx command and it all worked beautifully. I just typed:
npx create-medusa-app@latest

I realised there is now Postgres 16, so for some reason I decided to try to get it. I uninstalled Postgres 15 and installed 16 for Windows using their installer.
Now when I try to install MedusaJS I get this error:
Failed with error SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string

I've tried everything I can think of. I've tried to make the superadmin password blank, I've made it postgres, I've made it password.
I don't know what I need to do to get it working again?
